# vue add electron-builder: Manual workaround?

Tags: node.js, electron-builder

I'm following the book Vue.js 3 By Example (John Au-Yeung).
In chap4, the task is Creating a project with Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder.
I did below after the standard vue project was created:

```
vue add electron-builder
```

And I got below error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\data\projects\chap4\node_modules\electron-chromedriver
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./download-chromedriver.js
npm ERR! node:internal/process/promises:279
npm ERR!             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
npm ERR!             ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! GotError [RequestError]: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\data\projects\chap4\node_modules\got\source\request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:539:35)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\data\projects\chap4\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\source\index.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
```

As I ran it in a company issued PC, I know it's related to some restrictions of download files.

Can i download the chromedriver manually to by pass the error?
I have no idea how.
Apprecaite your input

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me was to add `ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY=true` for the install, this is an example with 'npm':

```
npx cross-env ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY=true npm install electron-builder
```

There should be something similar with 'vue'